# localDB on new client

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have created a c# console application with local db via [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w2JkLcp-UA).

I tried to create a release of this application and run it in another machine without success. I want to create a fully application that will run on a new machine without any other installations. Is it possible?

Comment: You can copy the mdf and ldf (log files) to new machine and then attach the files to c# project.  Did you publish the application which will create a setup.exe folder like purchase software?  Use the publish a Use CD or DVD option.  Location of files do not need to be on a CD.

Comment: @jdweng I have created a release via this [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w7axy17.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and copied the release directory to the new machine, the mdf&ldf files in this directory too. How do I attached them?

Comment: The instructions to attach should be int the proj file which is text.  You can open the proj with notepad to verify.  If not then use menu Tools : Connect to database and choose datasource.

Comment: @jdweng, I have the following code: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBConnectionStr"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\imagesDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>`  but it still isnt wok on my new machine,

Comment: probably I need to config something but I don't know what,

Comment: Simple.  The PC needs SQL Server install (if not already) then you need to attach the database to the server using SQL Server Management Studio which comes with SQL Server.

Comment: @jdweng My DB attached now to the new machine but I still cant access the db from my app. Do I need to do something else? maybe something in connectionString?

Comment: Probably a credential issue.  You may need an admin to fix.  Inte‌​grated Security=True indicates database is using a window credential.  When you attached you may not have given the database correct credential.  You should atttached db using sql script : CREATE DATABASE [<database_name>]
ON
(NAME = <database_name>,
    FILENAME = ‘<full path and database file name>’)
LOG ON
(NAME = <log_name>,
    FILENAME = ‘<full path and log file name>’)
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG

Comment: @jdweng still not working, it fails on "connect.open()" (connect is an sqlConnection)

Comment: I'm almost sure it is a credential issue.  Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  Check instance of database in login window which should match connection string :(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB. Use the explorer and check under database that imagesDB exists.  Then under database : Tables find your table.  Right click  "Select Top 1000 Rows"

Comment: When I connect to SSMS, on "connect to Database Engine"  window - I use on my hostname "MSEDGEWIN10", I don't have an option connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB...maybe this is my problem. How Can I fix it?right now I'm connect to "MSEDGEWIN10" and attached my DB to this, and I can see my table...but my application cant connect to this connection

Comment: LocalDB should be set automatically to "MSEDGEWIN10" .  I don't think that is the issue.  The instance name  MSSQLLocalDB is usually the issue.  When SQL Server gets installed depending on the version and number of instances of the server will depend on the name MSSQLLocalDB.  You can edit the xml so the instance matches the instance on the login window.

Comment: I try to change it from (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB  to MSEDGEWIN10 without success..

Comment: I'm have another machine with vs installed and my application run correctly but when I attached my DB, it response like the old one(cant connect.open())

Comment: The issue is either with the credentials or the instance of the database.  First attempt to access the data using SSMS as a said earlier.  This will tell us if the issue is the credentials or the instance.

Comment: @jdweng I created a new machine and try two things: first, I tried to run it without any preparation and it's stack, second - I tried to open the project and my localDB on vs, and after that my application run well(I didn't do anything on vs, and I run my program release from yesterday). my question is, there is another way to create a localDB(even independently from vs) that I can deploy and use on new machine without any preparation(like attached ect.) or installation?Is it possible?Thanks.

Comment: In the first try, I had sql server installed on my machine.

Comment: Normal method is to create a schema in working machine and then load on new machine.  Schema will load database structure only and not data.  You can copy entire database with data.  The database owns the file so you first have to deattach the database from server.  Then make a copy of the database.  Then attach the database back on original PC and do same with copy on new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the database which is set up in the tutorial is hosted locally on your machine when the app is started, which means the application cannot connect to the database when it is started on a device which does not run your database.
Usually when working with a database you have to set up a network connection in your application-code to access a database hosted on an external server. There are even some websites who let you set up a mysql database for free like this one: https://www.000webhost.com/)

There you can set up your database using a GUI tool named phpmyadmin which is kind of intuitive.
The next thing to do is set up a network connection to the database server inside your application which is usually an easy thing to do since you can use plenty of libraries built just for that. Details are provided here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

The Method of programming shown in the video you mentioned is largely dedicated to beginners and is not really applicable. You would have to deploy you application with a "copy" of the database and some kind of wizard to set it up on every new device, which is not a very clever way to go here.

Comment: I want to "move" my localDB to new machine and work there locally, without  DB on external host or web DB. Is it possible? maybe I need to define a new DB but I don't know how to define this kind of db(if it possible...)